# Estimation and comparison of flowering curves

Tags: regression, curves

I am a research scholar and monitoring phenological events of timber line at Himalayan region from past 4 years. During data analysis I found a research paper [Estimation and comparison of flowering curve](http://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1080/17550874.2011.580382#.UgdVIdJHLgs) similar to my work.

In this paper bbmle package was used and five parameters ($β_0, ... β_4$) describe: (i) the height; (ii) the peak date; (iii) the range; (iv) the symmetry; and (v) the peakedness of the regression curve was calculated. I also read the appendix table and followed the code to estimate these parameter but as a newbie I failed to calculate.

Appendix

```
library(bbmle) ## depends R(≥ 2.0.0)
## Collect data together as a data frame,
fdat <- data.frame(Days=c(212:238,250:271),
Count=c(0,2,2,6,10,18,29,39,59,75,104,130,
145,169,193,209,216,227,231,214,212,226,242,
225,214,202,211,104,90,70,55,52,45,38,29,22,
14,15,14,13,11,6,5,4,3,2,1,1,0))
## Define function
GESN <- function(x,b0,b1,b2,b3,b4) {
exp(b0-abs(((x-b1)/(b2∗(1+b3∗(sign(x-b1))))))ˆ(b4))
}
## Get reasonable starting values
startvals <- list(b0=log(250),b1=230,b2=15,b3=0,b4=2)
```

Please help me to find these parameters as they are mentioned in figure number 5 (link 1).

Answer (score 2):

You have not provided the full code, so I'll just go with the code you have provided. It seems to me that you have a simple syntax error in the second line because you copy&pasted from the paper. You have

```
GESN <- function(x,b0,b1,b2,b3,b4) { exp(b0-abs(((x-b1)/(b2∗(1+b3∗(sign(x-b1))))))ˆ(b4)) }
```

but you need (note the difference between circumflex  ˆ and caret ^)

```
GESN <- function(x,b0,b1,b2,b3,b4) { exp(b0-abs(((x-b1)/(b2∗(1+b3∗(sign(x-b1))))))^(b4)) }
```

Maybe give this a shot with the full code and report back if it does not work? In general, when copy&pasting from papers and similar sources, check every line very carefully to make sure that all special characters are correct.

Comment: thank you sir. I dont know how to attach linked research paper here so its my request  to download that paper once. In this paper author provided a data in appendix and the five estimated parameters. The four estimated parameters are provided in figure 5. My main problem comes here. I dont know to calculate these parameter. For e.g. the maximum number of flowers is on 232. But he said it on 230 by maximum likelihood estimation. Also i dont understand the meaning of spread of flowering which is 15. Could you please help me to calulate these parameter with the help to appendix data

Answer (score 0):

The full appendix table is here:

[image: Appendix]

I am also posting the startvals for the year 2007 as mention in appendix. look the values in figure below for year 2007..

[image: Figure 5 summarises the confidence limits on the fitted parameters and their variation from one year to the next.]

the main problem is how to calculate startvals for example data of year 2007 as shown in figure where (β0, ... β4) describe: (i) the height; (ii) the peak date; (iii) the range;
(iv) the symmetry; and (v) the peakedness of the regression curve.

Please help